# Create-react-app ServiceWorker broken in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, service-worker, create-react-app

Create-react-app ServiceWorker does not work in Chrome. White page with source code is shown when refreshing the browser. See screenshot below. This problem does not exist in Safari and Firefox.

Steps to reproduce:

1. create-react-app foo
2. cd foo
3. npm install
4. change serviceWorker.unregister() to serviceWorker.register() in index.js
5. npm run build
6. serve -s build
7. open http://localhost:5000 (or whatever port number is shown) in Chrome.
8. refresh browser after you see spinning react logo
9. now white page with source code is shown instead (see screenshot below)

Do you get the same or is it just my Chrome? Any idea what causes this problem?

[image]

Comment: Hi, I cannot reproduce what you describe. Any browser console logs? Was the service-worker correctly installed? Was this white page served by the service-worker or by the server?

Comment: No nothing in the console log. Everything default create-react-app with registered serviceWorker and built with npm run build and serve -s build. Problem only in Chrome on MacOS Mojave 10.14.4.